# Recursive factorial return statement

Tags: c, recursion, return-value, factorial

Why do we use `return 1` to terminate the recursive function? Can any other value be used as a default value like 1.

And if we return 1 as return value of the function, then why 1 is not returned to main function.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int fact(int n)
 {
   if(n>=1)
      return (n*fact(n-1));
   else
      return 1;
 }
 int main()
 {
   int a,ans;
   scanf("%d",&a);
   ans=fact(a);
   printf("factorial of %d is %d ",a,ans);
   return 0;
  }
  /*
   explanation
          fact(4);
          if(4>=1) 4*fact(3)
          if(3>=1) 4*3*fact(2)
          if(2>=1) 4*3*2*fact(1)
          if(1>=1) 4*3*2*1*fact(0)
          if(0>=1) return 1;

  */
```

Comment: Because 0! is 1.

Comment: Your comment is the answer. You are calling `fact(4)`, not `fact(0)`

Comment: please only tag the language you are using. Your question is rather unclear. Try  `fact(0)` and use a debugger to see that `1` is indeed returned to `main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if (n >= 1)
        return n * fact(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Each time the `fact()` function is called, it runs either the `return n * fact(n-1);` statement OR the `return 1;` statement but not both.

You call `fact(4)` in `main()`. This is how it runs:

```
main:
  compute fact(4)
  fact(4):
  |  4 >= 1?  Yes!
  |  compute 4 * fact(3)
  |    fact(3):
  |    |  3 >= 1?  Yes!
  |    |  compute 3 * fact(2)
  |    |    fact(2):
  |    |    |  2 >= 1? Yes!
  |    |    |  compute 2 * fact(1)
  |    |    |    fact(1):
  |    |    |    |  1 >= 1? Yes!
  |    |    |    |  compute 1 * fact(0)
  |    |    |    |    fact(0):
  |    |    |    |    |  0 >= 1? NO!
  |    |    |    |    |  return 1;
  |    |    |    |    +--> 1
  |    |    |    |  fact(0) is 1, return 1 * 1 (--> 1)
  |    |    |    +--> 1
  |    |    |  fact(1) is 1, return 2 * 1 (--> 2)
  |    |    +--> 2
  |    |  fact(2) is 2, return 3 * 2 (--> 6)
  |    +--> 6
  |  fact(5) is 6, return 4 * 6 (--> 24)
  +--> 24
  fact(4) is 24, assign it to `ans`, print it etc
// end of main
```

When a function uses the `return` statement (or after it executes its last statement if a `return` is not reached, the control is passed back to the expression that has called it.

Answer (score 3):

> why do we use "return 1" to terminate the recursive function

Because this is supposed to cover the case for when `n` is not `>=1`, in other words when `n` is `0`. I don't think negative `n` are valid. `0!` is `1`, hence why it returns that value.

> And if we return 1 as end of function, then why 1 is not returned to
>   main function.

If the function is called with `0` or `1` for `n`, then `1` is returned to the main function. For any other value, `1` is only returned in the recursive factorial calls and the value which is returned to the `main` function isn't `1`, but `(n*fact(n-1))`, which isn't `1` in those cases.

Comment: `then why 1 is not returned to main function.`.. I think that's a bit different from what you explained in the last paragraph.

Comment: Good catch. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The return statement is executed when `n==0`.

The factorial for `n==0` is 1, so we return 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /*
      explanation
          fact(4);
          if(4>=1) 4*fact(3)
          if(3>=1) 4*3*fact(2)
          if(2>=1) 4*3*2*fact(1)
          if(1>=1) 4*3*2*1*fact(0)
          if(0>=1) return 1; now return is default tend to multiply as we give 1 and 
           return has already 24 in its stack so 1*24 is returned to main()
          if we give return 2; 2*24 is returned to main();

    */
```

we don't want our final result to be affected, to solve that error, anything multiple by 1 will result the same, so we use 1 as return in recursive function.

Actually return is also a stack register which holds temporary variable while calling with in the function, and it operates default by multiply property, as we can send only one return value always.